# How to add in pop-up to jtextFiled view in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popup, jtextfield

I have developed a java gui that contains two jTextField views for displaying the source and destination file paths. And , the user selects more than one file path , i would like to display previous paths in a pop-up attached to the jTextField. This is a common feature in almost all app.
Does anyone knows how this is called, in order to google how to do it?

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list/14194104#14194104) similar answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called editable `JComboBox`.