# Java GUI searching database

Tags: java, search, user-interface, dynamic

In my program I have created an excel sheet with many names. In a gui there is a text field. What i want is when user starts entering character(s), all the names beginning with those character(s) from the excel sheet should be pulled out and displayed. If the user enters more characters the list should change accordingly. Also user should be able to select one of those names with the mouse for further processing.
eg :
Excel Sheet
Andy
Angle
Alice
Australia
John
Jane

user starts entering 'a'
output :
Andy
Angle
Alice
Australia

next letter 'an'
output:
Andy
Angel
 and so on
Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a basic question

Comment: You should probably implement something that combines an excel file parser within a thing that constantly checks the value of the input field and adjusts the recommendations in pseudo real-time

Comment: What you have tried so far ? programming in web or a swing application ?

Comment: You're going to need a `DocumentListener` for the text field

Comment: SSCcE of what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

- To avoid having to search the file over and over, you'll want to store the data in some sort of data structure.
- You'll also want to employ a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to check for every time the document is change (i.e. a letter is typed or deleted from the text field
- Depending on how you want the data displayed, you then would update the view's model accordingly base of the matched input in the text field.
- A suggestion is maybe to use a `JList`.
- Another option is to implement an auto-complete text field like exampled in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194104/2587435), that also uses the `DocumentListener`. I'm sure you can also search for other auto-complete Java implementations also.