# How to make a dropdown in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need to make a text box which autocompletes what the user is typing.  I want something like a JComboBox that can update whenever the user types a new character based off of a set of possibilities.  I want to do this by creating my own custom component by either extending JPanel or JComponent.  What I am unsure about is how do I make a frame which can float over all other content.  Like when you hit the drop down for a JComboBox how can I put a list of possibilities which floats above the background and underneath the text box?

Comment: You might find some help from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list).

Comment: You have at last three choices, either JPopupMenu or JWindow or an undecorated JFrame/JDialog

Answer (score 1):

You need import [SwingX](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/) (last version) on your project:

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;
```

[AutoCompleteDecorator](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html) this class contains only static utility methods that can be used to set up automatic completion for some Swing components.

Pass your JComboBox to the static method:

```
jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "alejandro", "berenice", "juan", "ana", "bartolo", "diana", "cesar" }));
jComboBox1.setName("jComboBox1");
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.jComboBox1);
```

Comment: That works but the only problem is I want to user to also be able to type things outside the range of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jide components, they are built on swing and provide more advance gui features than swing.