# Spring mvc autocomplete textbox

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I want to make a autocomplete textbox. I have an Entity Location

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int lId;
private String lName;

public Location() {
    super();
}

public Location(int lId, String lName) {
    super();
    this.lId = lId;
    this.lName = lName;
}
//getters and setters
```

It should be something like this

[image]

I have no idea how to complete this task. I have tried jQuery Autocomplite, but it wasn't success. Can anyone explaine me, how can i make it works. 
I have already tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/) solution. But it didn't help me. It doesnt work.

Comment: Is this in Java or C#, because the code and tags suggests Java, but your Window1 form suggests C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a autocompleting textbox in Java with a dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use a third-party library then use this: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194104/4985572)

Else if you don't mind using third-party code, then you could use this one:

`GlazedList` implementation auto-completion.

You can install `GlazedList` on a `JComboBox` with only one line of Glazed code, like this:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
Object[] elements = new Object[] {"name person", "name person", "name person", "name person"};
AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboBox, GlazedLists.eventListOf(elements));
```

Glazed Lists: [source](http://www.glazedlists.com/)