# How to make autoComplete text suggestion on Editor-IntelliJ plugin-Swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellij-plugin

I am started developing a plugin for IntelliJ platform and I am working with the Editor. So The problem is I have to make a popup when the user writes in an editor like the IntelliJ code completion works( when `ctrl+space`).

So I have an Editor inflated on a Jpanel. But I can't find any documentation on how to make popup while typing. But I have found some projects using ComboBoxes with Close, minimise maximise option within it. I don't want that.

I am a noob on this.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a autocompleting textbox in Java with a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list)

Comment: If you want to do it by yourself, look the classes `PopupFactory` and `Popup`

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development would be the proper place for this kind of questions.

Comment: You have to use `CompletionContributor` https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/completion_contributor.html